# Django many to many field : Queryset values

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the following in django 1.8 :

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return u"{0} {1}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

I would like to get a queryset that has the following format:

```
results = [{"title":"title1","authors":['first_name last_name', 'first_name last_name']
```

So all the many_to_many objects are grouped into a list.

The query i'm used to perform for these cases is :

```
results = Article.objects.all().prefetch_related('authors').values('title','authors')
```

I can solve the issue by looping into each object and constructing a new dictionary, but it becomes a bottleneck after +100 items.

```
    results = []
    for element in Article.objects.all().prefetch_related('authors'):
        results.append(dict(title=element.title, 
authors=[b.full_name for b in element.authors.all()]))
```

Is there a django way to solve this issue ?

Comment: There is no built-in in the Django ORM that I can recall. However, maybe if you share the custom code you tried and explain a little more what the "bottleneck" is, some answers could be offered.

Comment: You only want the authors formatted as string? or do you want the objects itself?

Comment: @Sebastian : the question is updated with a custom solution.

Comment: @Gocht : Formatted as string

Comment: Are you familiar with `select_related` and familiar with the differences to `prefetch_related`? Is there a reason you preferred one over the other?

Comment: @Sebastian :  You use select_related when the object that you're going to be selecting is a single object, so OneToOneField or a ForeignKey. You use prefetch_related when you're going to get a "set" of things, so ManyToManyFields

Comment: @TheOtherGuy I wouldn't agree with that statement. `prefetch_related` will execute a separate query for the related model and then join the results in Python, whereas `select_related` will perform the join on the DB server. Which will perform better really depends on your data, query, available indexes and database server.

Answer (score 0):

Something I would try is the following:

```
results = []
authors = Author.objects.only('full_name')
qs = Article.objects.only('title').prefetch_related('authors', queryset=authors)
for element in qs:
    results.append(
        dict(
            title=element.title, 
            authors=[b.full_name for b in element.authors.all()]
        )
    )
```

OR

```
results = []
qs = Article.objects.select_related('authors').only('title', 'author__full_name')
for element in qs:
    results.append(
        dict(
            title=element.title, 
            authors=[b.full_name for b in element.authors.all()]
        )
    )
```

This basically amounts to reducing the amount of data fetched from the server by querying only the required columns and then trying select_related instead of prefetch_related (whether this helps or not depends heavily on the your actual data).